# Advantages of Set in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, set

The main advantage of `Set` seems to be maintaining unique elements. But that can be easily achieved in `Array` with,

```
array = [2,3,4]
array | [2,5,6] # => [2,3,4,5,6]
```

The only distinct feature (which could apply to few use-cases) I came across was,

```
set1 = [1,2,3].to_set
set2 = [2,1,3].to_set
set1 == set2 # => true
[1,2,3] == [2,1,3] # => false
```

Since `Array` has various functions and operations associated with it, when and why should I use `Set`?

There are many links that compare `Array` and `Set` but I haven't come across significant application of `Set`.

Comment: This is a broad question and strongly defined by opinions. As you already said, it all depends on use cases. The fact you have found few use cases for sets does not mean this is the same for all.

Comment: I'm new to programming and ruby. When I mentioned 'few use cases', I only meant my lack of exposure. I was hoping to understand sets and its applications better by looking at how others have implemented (applied) it. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, Prashanth. Don't take it personally. I just meant that this is very personal and can''t be generalized easily.

Answer (score 18):

Sure, whatever you can do with `Set`, there is a way to do it with `Array`. The advantage of using a `Set` is that, since it is implemented based on `Hash`, most operations on it are O(1) complexity, while doing it with `Array` can be O(n).

Examples are:

```
Set.new([1, 2, 3]).include?(2) # O(1) complexity
[1, 2, 3].include?(2) # O(n) complexity
```

Comment: It would be great to have a) a prooflink and b) more concrete list of “most” operations.

Comment: Should be amortized O(1) complexity, due to dynamic resizing.

Answer (score 8):

These two classes defines different data structures:

## Arrays

- can have duplicated elements
- maintains orders
- can be iterated in order
- searching for element is slow, appending element and getting element from position is fast
- maintaining uniqueness of elements is slow

## Sets

- can't have duplicated elements
- don't have ordering (theoretical background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)
- searching for existence of element is fast, appending element is fast
- uniqueness is given by design

Sets are actually taken from math concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Internally inside Ruby set use hash for storage, as said in documentation:

> Set uses Hash as storage, so you must note the following points:
>
> Equality of elements is determined according to Object#eql? and
>   Object#hash. Set assumes that the identity of each element does not
>   change while it is stored. Modifying an element of a set will render
>   the set to an unreliable state. When a string is to be stored, a
>   frozen copy of the string is stored instead unless the original string
>   is already frozen.

When you look into the code, it's internally stored as hash with user given objects as keys and boolean as values (to be precise: true when object is added).

Why one should use set? If you want to enforce uniqueness and you don't need any ordering - sets are your best choice. When you don't really care about uniqueness and ordering is important - Array is your choice.

Otherwise - you need to decide arbitrally ;)

Answer (score 7):

For the obvious reasons, see the other answers here.
For performance reasons, see the result of this little benchmark in MRI Ruby 1.9.3:

```
require 'benchmark' 
require 'set' 

array = (1..100000).to_a 
set = array.to_set 
#hash = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, nil]}] #beter voor heel grote volumes mar trager
hash = Hash[*array]

Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report("Set.include?")   { 10000.times { set.include?(99999) } }
  x.report("Array.include?") { 10000.times { array.include?(99999) } } 
  x.report("Hash.include?")  { 10000.times { hash.include?(99999) } } 
end
```

which gives

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------
Set.include?     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.015604)
Array.include?  37.940000   0.000000  37.940000 ( 38.651992)
Hash.include?    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001000)
---------------------------------------- total: 37.940000sec

                     user     system      total        real
Set.include?     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002001)
Array.include?  38.157000   0.000000  38.157000 ( 38.730615)
Hash.include?    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001001)
```

Enough reason to use `Set` or `Hash` when possible.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you can achieve the same results using Ruby `Arrays` and `Sets`. But, the same can be said about Ruby's `Modules` and `Classes`. You can have variables and methods in both, but they serve the different purpose and when someone else reads the code, s/he will get that meaning without trying to figure out your design decisions.

I guess the case of `Sets` and `Arrays` is the same. You can *achieve* the same result using arrays, but with sets your variables convey additional information about your business logic (contents must be unique). Basically, they are different data structures. There is a reason we have different data structures.

Secondly, with sets your code is more readable, when you do operations like `.subset?`, `.superset?`, `.intersect?`, etc. The new comers would be guessing what `array | array` operation does, but with sets it is all there. See which one is more readable:

```
([1, 2, 3] & [2, 3]).empty?          # => false
Set[1, 2, 3].intersect? Set[2, 3]    # => true
```

Thirdly, the intersection operations with sets are *probably* pre-optimised and may run faster.