# Ruby - Compare arrays and get index based on condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, set, compare

I have two arrays

```
array_input = %w[one two three two]
array_compare = %w[one two three four five]
```

I want to extract the 'highest' index from the array_compare array, if the value exists in the input array. The desired output is `2` as `three` exists in the input array and the `compare` array.

I've tried

```
val = nil
array_compare.reverse_each do |v|
  val = v and break if array_input.include? v
end
```

but it does not set val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could write

```
array_compare.rindex { |e| array_input.include?(e) }
  #=> 2
```

but that requires a linear search of `array_input` for each element of `array_compare` (starting with the last) until a match is found. Better is the following.

```
array_compare.rindex((array_compare & array_input).last)
  #=> 2
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = array_compare & array_input
  #=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

See [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26). Note that "The order is preserved from the original array [`array_compare`].". This one-pass operation will be very fast as it is implemented in C. Continuing,

```
e = a.last
  #=> "three" 
array_compare.rindex(e)
  #=> 2
```

See [Array#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rindex).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand properly,

> extract the 'highest' index from the array_compare array, if the value exists in the input array,

this could be an option:

```
array_compare.map.with_index { |e, id| id if array_input.include? e }.compact.max #=> 2
```

---

If `array_compare = %w[one two three four five three]`, it returns `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the array used for lookups to a [set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), for faster lookup.
Iterate from the end of the array where you are searching for the max index (as you are correctly doing), also for speed. Solutions that iterate from the beginning of the array and choose the max index are generally slower due to all the useless lookups until the last matching element is found. The method below stops quickly - at the first successful match.
Finally, correct the max index, since `array_compare.reverse.each_with_index` returns indexes of the *reversed* array.
The resulting code may be longer than in many of the other answers, but it is both simple and fast:

```
require 'set'
array_input = %w[one two three two]
array_compare = %w[one two three four five]
set_input = array_input.to_set
i_max = nil
array_compare.reverse.each_with_index { |x, i| i_max = i and break if set_input.include? x }

# correct the index to count from the beginning of 
# array_compare, not from the end:
i_max = array_compare.length - i_max - 1;

puts i_max; # prints: 2
```

**SEE ALSO:**

Array.include? is relatively slow. Also, if you need a hash for lookup only, consider using a set: https://stackoverflow.com/a/411164/967621

More about speed comparisons for arrays, sets, and hashes (with benchmarks): [Advantages of Set in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36548938/967621)

Answer (score 1):

The most performant solution that I could come up with is:

```
def find_last_index(set_input, array_compare)
  (array_compare.length - 1).downto(0) do |i|
    return i if set_input.include?(array_compare[i])
  end
end
```

Note that the argument `set_input` is a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), not an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). Converting an array to a set makes sense, but only if you want to call `find_last_index` many times with the same set. Otherwise the process of converting an array to a set (`to_set`) takes more time, than you can gain using a `Set#include?` instead of an `Array#include?`. So if you want to use `find_last_index` only once, you shouldn't call `find_last_index(array_input.to_set, array_compare)`, but instead use this version that don't use sets at all:

```
def find_last_index(array_input, array_compare)
  (array_compare.length - 1).downto(0) do |i|
    return i if array_input.include?(array_compare[i])
  end
end
```

You might want to see [this benchmark](https://onlinegdb.com/SymtuK5fv) of different solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just executed (copy&paste) your code in *irb*, and `val` was "three" afterwards. Did you actually inspect `val` afterwards, i.e.

```
p val
```

? Here is [a screenshot of my transscript](https://ibb.co/N1XtCP1).

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I think it's kind of an answer, because it explains (and demonstrates) that the original code is fine, and shows  a proof that the variable has the expected value. I admit that this answer is so short that it also could be a comment. I did not show an alternative implementation of how to reach the result, since this was not asked.