# How to simply write multiple comparisons using || with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I want to write the conditions as such, but it's too long.
How can I make it more simple?

```
if A
  ~~~
elsif B == b || B == c || B == d || B == e   <-- This part is too long.
  ~~~
else
  ~~~
end
```

I thought it could be written as below, but it gave me an error, when I tried it on rails console.

```
elsif B == (b || c || d || e)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can it be written as below"? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Depends what the objects are. Why not do `elsif [b, c, d, e].include? B`

This also depends what you mean by 'making more simple?' It might be that writing a case statement is better on a compiled level, etc.

Comment: Another way: `...elsif; case(B); when b,c,d,e; ~~~~~; end; else; ~~~~; end`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if B == b || B == c || B == d || B == e
```

can be written as

```
if [b, c, d, e].include?(B)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

*[EDIT] (Thanks to the comment from Sergio Tulentsev) This is only relevant for longer arrays, more than about 10 elements, not in the exact case described by the OP. I include this answer for other users who may have longer arrays or lists of comparisons. [/EDIT]*

If speed is also an issue: use a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), which has a faster `include?` compared to `Array`:

```
# at the top, load this standard library (comes with Ruby):
require 'set'
# ...
if [b, c, d, e].to_set.include?(B)
```

**SEE ALSO:**

Array.include? is relatively slow. For lookups, use a set instead of a hash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/411164/967621

Speed comparisons for arrays, sets, and hashes, with benchmarks: [Advantages of Set in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36548938/967621)

Comment: "Array.include? is relatively slow" - no, not really. On small arrays (< ~10 elements), finding a random element is just as fast as with hashes/sets. But, of course, it falls behind as arrays get larger (because of O(N) complexity).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the suggestion, edited.

Comment: Here's the benchmark I used, btw: https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/bdfb5c22b641b9dac6e30561dc209e51

Comment: Of course `Set#include?` is much faster than `Array#include?` – a set can answer the question in just one step whereas an array needs to iterate all elements. But `to_set` needs to hash each element and therefore iterates all elements too. Therefore the question is not how many elements there are in the array but how often you will need to call `includes?` on the collection? For a small number of `include?` calls an array will be faster because you save the `to_set` call which is quite expensive. For a bigger number, a set will win.