# Filter an array of hashes to keep only those elements whose hashes contain a key contained in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

Here we have an array of hashes. How can we keep only the hashes for which at least one key is contained in an array?

```rb
# array of hashes
@arr_of_h = [{first: 10},
{second: 10, secondB: 10},
{third: 10, thirdB: 10}]

# array
arr = ["first", "third"]
```

Desired output

```
@output = [{:first=>10}, {:third=>10, :thirdB=>10}]
```

Comment: If the hashes can have more than one key I suggest you modify your example so that at least one element of `@arr_of_h` is a hash with more than one key. In any case, you need to edit your question to clarify whether hashes always have a single key.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see your point (much more useful for the community if the question/solution solves a general rather than specific problem). I think the question can be easily edited, but I am not sure about the answers? if it creates a confusing situation, I could ask a new question specifying multiple keys per hash (and edit this question to focus on one key per hash and hence not having to change answers). But I will take your advice. Let me know what's best and I'll do it

Comment: Questions should not be changed after an answer has been posted, but clarifications are always encouraged. Had you initially stated that all hashes have a single key changing that now to say that hashes can have more than one key would clearly change the question, but that's not the situation. Even though all hashes in your example have one key, I don't think it can be reasonably inferred that you are only concerned about one-key hashes (but that point is debatable)...

Comment: ...I suggest you edit the question to clarify whether hashes can have more than one key. (After all, the point of SO is to help you solve your problem.) If hashes can have more than one key I suggest you alter your example to include at least one hash with multiple keys and leave comments on those answers that assumed all hashes have one key, apologizing for the ambiguity. Those comments will alert them to the clarification, giving them an opportunity to revise their answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland nice. I think I edited the question accordingly. Please feel free to edit if it doesn't make sense or can be made simpler / more easily generalisable

Comment: @CarySwoveland I *think* 2 of the three answers work with the updated question, so i have only commented on the one answer that doesn't. If am incorrect please inform. Thanks for your advice. I think the effort is worth it so as to make life easy for anyone that arrives here in the future

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think everything's in good order now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below with [Array select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select):

> `select` will return an array containing elements which match the condition provided on the block.

Hope the hash on every index of the array will include only one key

```
 @arr_of_h.select{ |element| arr.include?(element.keys.first.to_s) }
```

**EDIT #1**

> To find the record which at least has one key contained in an array

We can achieve it through [Array select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select) and [Array any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F)

```
 @arr_of_h.select{ |element| element.keys.any? {|element| arr.include?(element.to_s) }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It helped me a lot! @Cary has pointed out the question was ambiguous, so I clarified and made it more generalisable. Is it possible to update the answer to match the updated question?

Comment: Sure @stevec Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would work if you have hashes in your array with more than one key and you wanted to keep hashes if one of the hash keys was present the 'keep' array.

```
arr_of_h.delete_if { |hash| (arr & (hash.keys.map(&:to_s))).empty? }
```

As Cary rightfully pointed out, this does mutate the array. If you do not wish to mutate the array:

```
arr_of_h.select { |hash| (arr & (hash.keys.map(&:to_s))).any? }
```

Answer (score 2):

If speed is important, and if the array has many elements, which translates to many lookups, use a `set`. Also, for speed, convert the array to symbols at the beginning, rather than converting it in the `select` loop. Note that for the particular case described by the OP, the speed improvements would be tiny if any, since all inputs are small.

```
require "Set"
@arr_of_h = [{first: 10}, {second: 10}, {third: 10}]
arr = ["first", "third"]
arr_as_set = arr.map(&:to_sym).to_set
@output = @arr_of_h.select { |h| arr_as_set.include?(h.keys.first) }
puts @output
# Prints: 
# {:first=>10}
# {:third=>10}
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`Set#include?` docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F)
[`Set#include?` vs. `Array#include?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63507962/967621)
[More on `Set#include?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411164/967621)
[Speed comparisons for arrays, sets, and hashes, with benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36548938/967621)